# jQuery conflict in SP Portfolio Joomla Extension

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

Can you help with solving this? I am usning Joomla 3.0 for my website http://www.vl-studios.com/lovetravel2.ge and I have problem with SP Portfolio Joomla extension. Thier team told me that I have to use jquery no conflict, but I don't know how to do this.

Can you help me? there is filter which is not working.

Comment: You already have jQuery noConflict which is coming from `/lovetravel2.ge/plugins/system/jqueryeasy/jquerynoconflict.js`

Comment: @Lodder yes, I installed this, thout that it will help, but still no result. How can I see which extension causes conflict?

Comment: There is no way to find the extension that is causing the problem. If you use the browser inspector, you will see a few errors but some of them are due to not being able to find jQueryUI and the others are for a different script file which I don't think will conflict. However I could be wrong so try fixing these errors first, else let the developer know that you have noConflict running so they can assist you in the next step

Comment: Thanks guys, I don't know what I did but it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

This article from jQuery's API explains how to use it: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/. Essentially it removes jQuery "owning" the $ variable.

Comment: If only I knew what to do next :)))

Comment: It explains in the article where to place the $.noConflict() code snippet. I have no idea where/how Joomla! generates its header tags from :)

Comment: is there any way to see whic extension causes conflict, maybe I can turn off that module

Comment: Disabling them one-by-one and seeing if it fixes the problem would unfortunately be the only way.

Comment: oh I found it is Blog Module. So, there is no way to turn make them work together right?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the variable $ to jQuery. It should resolve the conflicts